# How do I query info from 2 tables based on 2 variables?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select all from the table Apparel_Colors where the value Apparel_Color_Palette within the Apparel_Colors table equals the value Apparel_Color_Palette within the Apparel table, in which the Apparel_ID within the Apparel table equals 1.

My bad pseudo logic query:

```
select * 
from Apparel_Colors 
where Apparel_Colors.Apparel_Color_Palette = Apparel.Apparel_Color_Palette 
AND Apparel.Apparel_ID = 1;
```

Basically, I only know the Apparel_ID.  And, with the Apparel_ID I'm trying to get all the colors within the apparels color palette.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from apparel_colors
inner join Apparel_Color_Palette on apparel_colors.<field> = Apparel_Color_Palette.<field>
where Apparel.Apparel_ID = 1;
```

Showing us your table def would help.

Ok, with your table def, this is easy now.  You have to join the 2 tables.  You were not so far.

```
select *
from Apparel_Colors
inner join Apparel on Apparel_Colors.Apparel_Color_Palette = Apparel.Apparel_Color_Palette
where Apparel.Apparel_ID = 1;
```

Old syntax (very close to your query) :

```
select * from Apparel_Colors, apparel where Apparel_Colors.Apparel_Color_Palette = 
Apparel.Apparel_Color_Palette AND Apparel.Apparel_ID = 1;
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Ok.  I added a picture of my tables.

Comment: This works perfectly!  Thank you so much for your help.  I thought I might need a join, but for some reason, I really struggle with joins.  I need to study up.